# Dio not responding to closed API

Tags: flutter, dio

Im using an API to handle login and storing the token. The response will get a token if the credentials is valid and an error if the credentials is invalid. Right now it works fine I get the token and If there's an error the catch method displays it but when I close the API and make a POST request, I don't get any response at all. How do I handle the connection error with DIO ?

```
Future<bool> login(String email, String password) async {
  try {
    var data = {
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
      'device_name': 'mobile'
    };
    Response response = await _dio.post(
      url + 'sanctum/token',
      data: data,
      options: Options(
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
      ),
    );
    await _storage.write(key: 'token', value: response.toString());
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.response.toString());
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error log?

Comment: no. nothing @PreetShah

Comment: So, how do you know it is not working? Dio returns an error in case of any connection errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning `false` using `finally` instead of `catch`:

```
Future<bool> login(String email, String password) async {
  try {
    // Make the request here like you already are
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.response.toString());
  } finally {
    // This wouldn't get called if you already returned from the try block before, 
    // but would get called after catch if an exception was caught.
    return false; 
  }
}
```